# adding a new column using values in another column using pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data set

```
id     Category    Date
1       Sick      2016-10-10
                  12:10:21
2       Active    2017-09-08
                  11:09:06
3       Weak      2018-11-12
                  06:10:04
```

Now i want to add a new column which only has year in the data set using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 'Sick  ', '2016-10-10 12:10:21'],
        [2, 'Active', '2017-09-08 11:09:06'],
        [3, 'Weak  ', '2018-11-12 06:10:04']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'category', 'date'])

df['year'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.year

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
id category                 date  year
0   1   Sick    2016-10-10 12:10:21  2016
1   2   Active  2017-09-08 11:09:06  2017
2   3   Weak    2018-11-12 06:10:04  2018
```

Comment: @shrutyam Glad I could help, if my answer was helpful please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

you can just do `df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year`

Output:

```
    id  category    Date                year
0   1   Sick       2016-10-10 12:10:21  2016
1   2   Active     2017-09-08 11:09:06  2017
2   3   Weak       2018-11-12 06:10:04  2018
```